# Stop an angular-ui-router state change when a simple object can't be resolved?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

One of my angular-ui-router states depends on a **simple object** being resolved:

```
.state(...) {
  ...
  resolve: {
    user: function ($rootScope) {
      if ($rootScope.user) {
        return $rootScope.user;
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

I figured if the `$rootScope.user` object didn't exist, then the user dependency couldn't be resolved, and the state wouldn't change. Instead, even when `$rootScope.user` does not exist, user is resolved to an empty object `{}`, and the state does change.

Is there a way make the resolve fail when `$rootScope.user` does not exist? Perhaps by returning a specific value in an else block that signifies that the dependency could not be resolved?

I'm able to reject it using a **promise**:

```
resolve: {
  user: function($q) {
    return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
      if ($rootScope.user) {
        resolve($rootScope.user);
      }
      else {
        reject();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case when `$rootScope.user` does not exist, the promise is rejected, the user dependency is not resolved, and the state does not change.

Is there a way to do this without a promise? Why? Because using a promise here doesn't make it clear that a simple object needs to be resolved.

Comment: If you know that the `user` should have an `id` property (for example), then you can check `if( $rootScope.user and typeof($rootScope.user.id) === number)` to resolve the object

Comment: @AlonEitan I'm not sure I get your meaning. Can you elaborate? Knowing when the user is or is not defined is not the problem I'm facing. It's that in the first function, the user dependency always gets resolved no matter what. I'm looking for a way to reject that dependency when $rootScope.user is not defined. The only way I could figure that out was to use a promise.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you will use service/factory for this, it's not considerate a good practice to use `$rootScope` the share data between controllers. This data can be easily get overwritten (Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512158/is-storing-variables-in-rootscope-good-practice)

Comment: Based on everything I've read and tried, you can not use a service inside of `app.config()`.  Is that correct? Also, that's not really the issue here. I just want resolve to fail when a simple object does not exist.

Comment: No, but this is in the resolve and you can inject a service there (Into the resolve function) - For what you're actually asking, hope someone else will post a solution for that

Comment: I thought I tried that, but I'll look into it more thanks.

Comment: Are you using this method to check if user is login? If yes... check out $httpProvider interceptor. Instead of checking $rootScope make a fake call to the api to check if user is login and if user is not log in it will redirect to log in screen

Comment: @123456789 Yeah there are a lot of ways to check whether a user is logged in or not. The way I chose to do it this time is to make sure that a user is resolved before entering any state that requires a user. As I've said, I got it to work with promises. I'm really just trying to find out if its possible to stop a state change when a simple object can't be resolved. I read the docs and they weren't much.